# Canonical Skolem terms for structures with a well-ordering.

Tags: set-theory

So I started reading the chapter on Indiscrenibles and $0^\#$ in The Higher Infinite and I have some questions on Canonical Skolem terms. I will type the paragraph from the book below, sorry if it's long, but it contains the required definitions.

---

> By 3.3(a) there is a formula $\varphi_0(v_0, v_1)$ that defines in $L$ a well-ordering $\lt_L$ of $L$ s.t. for any limit $\delta \gt \omega$ and $x, y \in L_\delta$, $x \lt_L y$ iff $L_\delta \models \varphi_0[x, y]$. 
>   For each formula $\varphi(v_0, \dots, v_m)$ of $\mathfrak{L}_\in$, define the *Canonical Skolem term* $t_\varphi$ for $\varphi$ using $\varphi_0$ as follows:
>   $$ t_\varphi(v_1, \dots, v_m) = v_0 \text{ iff }(\forall v_{m+2} \neg \varphi(v_{m+2}, v_1, \dots, v_m) \land v_0 = \emptyset)  \lor (\varphi(v_0, v_1, \dots, v_m) \land\forall v_{m+1}( \varphi_0(v_{m+1}, v_0) \rightarrow \neg \varphi(v_{m+1}, v_1, \dots, v_m))). $$
>   For any $\mathfrak{M} = \langle M, E \rangle$ satisfying the requisite well-ordering properties of $\varphi_0$, the corresponding expansion $\langle M, E, t_{\varphi}^{\mathfrak{M}} \rangle_{\varphi}$, can be considered where the well-defined interpretation $t_{\varphi}^{\mathfrak{M}}$ is a Skolem function for $\varphi$ s.t. $t_{\varphi}^{\mathfrak{M}}$ is the least $y$ according to $\varphi_0$ satisfying $\mathfrak{M} \models \varphi[y, x_1, \dots, x_m]$ when one exists. Note that $\{ t_{\varphi}^{\mathfrak{M}}(x_1, \dots, x_m) : \varphi \text{ is a formula of } \mathfrak{L}_\epsilon \}$ is already closed under functional composition by definability, and hence is a complete set of Skolem functions for $\mathfrak{M}$.

---

So here are my questions:
Q1: Should'nt we consider the Skolem functions for each different context of each formula $\varphi$?Because I think if we fix only one context, then the other free variable won't be accounted for when placing existential quantifiers in arbitrary orders behind them.
Q2: I don't understand how definablity plays a role in showing these functions are closed under composition. For example what would the desired Skolem function for $t_{\varphi}^{\mathfrak{M}}(t_{\psi}^{\mathfrak{M}}(y_1, \dots, y_n), x_1, \dots, x_m)$ look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "different context of each formula"?

Comment: For example if we let $\varphi$ be $x = y$ then we can either look at it like $\varphi(x , y)$ or $\varphi(y, x)$. For more complicated formulas when $\varphi$ is not symmetric in its variables, then it seems having one Skolem term wouldn't be enough, would it?

Comment: You're thinking semantically. But formulas are syntactic. It's true, $\vdash x=y\leftrightarrow y=x$, this is one of the assumptions on $=$. But $x=y$ and $y=x$ are two different syntactic objects.

Comment: I know, but the thing is when I say that we have $\varphi(x, y)$ and $\varphi(y, x)$ I mean they correspond to the same formula $x = y$. I have just reversed the order of the context, not the formula. And because by definition, the Skolem functions find the minimum value of the first variable of the context, if it exists of course, that can cause trouble when we need values for other variables of the formula.

Comment: But now you're talking about *assignments*. The notation $\varphi(x,y)$ usually denotes that the free variables of $\varphi$ is a subset of $\{x,y\}$. The only meaningful difference between $\varphi(x,y)$ and $\varphi(y,x)$ is when that is an *assignment of value* in a model. In that situation you're going beyond syntax, again.

Comment: But when you say $\varphi(x, y)$ denotes the fact that the free variables of $\varphi$ are a subset of $\{x, y\}$ then how do we determine $v_0$ in the definition of Skolem terms?

Comment: There is a reason we use $v_i$ and not $x,y,z$ when we want to be truly formal. Look at the paragraph you quoted.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks! Any ideas on Q2?